# Calculate a field based on several rows selected by index value in R without looping?

Tags: r, loops, indexing, field, apply

I need to do classification / recoding based on several fields that are linked by OBJECTID.
In case your interested: My objects are river stretches, and i need to summarize/recode various ecology related parameters.

For this example I'm just doing a mean but in practice i need to implement more complicated recoding; f.e. OBJECT i falls in class 1 if 70% of the river stretch identified by the OBJECTID are OM < 2 or 80% are OM < 3, OBJECT i falls in class 2 if 50% of the river stretch are OM < 4 or 60% are OM 4 or 5, etc...)

```
Input                              Output

OBJECTID  OM                       OBJECTID  OM     OM_mean  
1         3.1                      1         3.1    5.13                      
1         8.2                      1         8.2    5.13
1         4.1       ----->         1         4.1    5.13
2         2.3                      2         2.3    6.2
2         9.1                      2         9.1    6.2
```

(yes i need it in this form, aggregate does not do what i need)

This is relatively easy to achieve using a for loop, however, my table is very large and the process is **atrociously slow** for my data (several days on a modern computer)

```
for(i in dat$OBJECTID) {
  a=dat[dat$OBJECTID == i,]
  dat$OM_mean[dat$OBJECTID == i]      = mean(a$OM)
  }
```

I was wondering if a more elegant/faster approach exists using something like apply, but i couldn't find a solution. I hope I was able to state my problem clearly.

Please correct me if used inappropriate terminology or if you think the topic title is not very clear, I'm relatively new to R and programming in general.

The actual function I am using for recoding (instead of the mean given in the example) is:

```
for(i in ecol_risk$OBJECTID) {
  a=ecol_risk@data[ecol_risk$OBJECTID == i,] # subset one river stretch of interest

  if(min(a$OM) %in% c(1,2,3,4,5)){  # Filters out some unwanted values

    b=aggregate(a$SLengthM, by=list(a$OM), FUN=sum)
    names(b) = c("OM", "SLengthM")
    b$frac = b$SLengthM/(sum(a$SLengthM)) # Calculate the % of total river stretch length
    b$frac12 = 0
      if(1 %in% b$OM & 2 %in% b$OM) { # get % for combination of two OM values
        b$frac12 = b$frac[b$OM == 1] + b$frac[b$OM == 2] 
      }
    b$frac45 = 0
    if(4 %in% b$OM & 5 %in% b$OM) {
      b$frac12 = b$frac[b$OM == 4] + b$frac[b$OM == 5] 
    }

    b$OM_agg = 3  # do some weird recoding

    b$OM_agg[b$frac >= 0.8 & b$OM == 5] = 4
    b$OM_agg[b$frac >= 0.8 & b$OM == 4] = 4
    b$OM_agg[b$bfrac45 >= 0.7] = 4

    b$OM_agg[b$frac >= 0.5 & b$OM == 1] = 2
    b$OM_agg[b$frac >= 0.7 & b$OM == 2] = 2
    b$OM_agg[b$frac12 >= 0.7] = 2  

    b$OM_agg[b$frac >= 0.8 & b$OM == 1] = 1
    b$OM_agg[b$frac >= 0.9 & b$OM == 2] = 1
    b$OM_agg[b$bfrac12 >= 0.9] = 1

    x = min(b$OM_agg)

    ecol_risk@data$OM_agg[ecol_risk$OBJECTID == i] = x

    print(i)
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks like your input is a data frame called `dat`; could we have the dimensions of that data frame or even better `str(dat)`?  And the `a =` bit in your code isn't used. Your basic task is to grab all rows that have the same OBJECTID and then do something with the other columns, correct?

Comment: I realise I have probably oversimplified my problem in the question. Sadly my R is occupied right now with the loop approach, i'll post real world data on Monday. also it should be mean(a$OM). fixed it in the question.

Comment: All good.  @shadow 's answer is a good one but it is a variation on `aggregate` (I need to study the differences between the two).  Either one allows you to pass a function which you'll need to write, but that's very powerful.

Comment: I now posted the whole code of my recoding function, something that I hoped to be able to avoid because it's really messy...  Though i have no idea how i would implement that as function that i could pass to aggregate or ave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to calculate the mean, then the `?ave` function is what you are looking for

```
dat[, "OM_mean"] <- ave(dat$OM, dat$OBJECTID, FUN=mean)
```

Since you apparently want to calculate many summary statistics with your `data.frame` and not just one, I suggest you use the `plyr` package instead. If you use the data you provided (together with a weight), dput(dat) gives:

```
dat <- structure(list(OBJECTID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), 
                      OM = c(3.1, 8.2, 4.1, 2.3, 9.1), 
                      weight = c(1, 1, 2, 1, 2)), 
                 .Names = c("OBJECTID", "OM", "weight"), 
                 row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Then you can use `ddply` from `plyr` to calculate your summaries.

```
# load package
require(plyr)
# split by OBJECTID and apply function
ddply(dat, "OBJECTID", function(x){
  x[,"OM_mean"] <- mean(x$OM) # mean
  x[,"OM_w.mean"] <- weighted.mean(x$OM, x$weight) # weighted mean
  return(x) # return the entire data.frame
})
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, is a million times faster than my for loop and has a fancy progress bar, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For max speed and simplicity of syntax, use `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
dt = data.table(your_data_frame)

dt[, OM_MEAN := mean(OM), by = OBJECTID]
```